# Convert between System.Data.SqlDbType and Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlDataType

Tags: c#, sql-server, enums

Given an instance of [System.Data.SqlDbType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype.aspx) how can I convert it to an instance of [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlDataType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.sqldatatype.aspx) and vice-versa?

The enums don't match up.

[image: Comparing enums]

Comment: I think you will have to write your own two methods with switch cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this if the names match, maybe?

```
 System.Data.SqlDbType otherEnumTypeValue = System.Data.SqlDbType.Xml;
 Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlDataTypeconverted = 
         (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlDataType)Enum.Parse(typeof(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlDataType), otherEnumTypeValue.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks, that will handle the core cases. The rest I'll need to handle depending on the direction of the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Conversion from SqlDataType to SqlDbType using Bala R's enum parsing code plus special cases for unsupported conversions.

```
private static SqlDbType ConvertSqlTypeEnum(SqlDataType sqlDataType)
        {
            SqlDbType sqlDbType;
            switch (sqlDataType)
            {
                case SqlDataType.UserDefinedType:
                    sqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Udt;
                    break;
                case SqlDataType.None:
                case SqlDataType.NVarCharMax:
                case SqlDataType.UserDefinedDataType:
                case SqlDataType.VarBinaryMax:
                case SqlDataType.VarCharMax:
                case SqlDataType.SysName:
                case SqlDataType.Numeric:
                case SqlDataType.UserDefinedTableType:
                case SqlDataType.HierarchyId:
                case SqlDataType.Geometry:
                case SqlDataType.Geography:
                    throw new NotSupportedException("Unable to convert to SqlDbType:" + sqlDataType);
                default:
                    sqlDbType = (SqlDbType)Enum.Parse(typeof(SqlDbType), sqlDataType.ToString());
                    break;
            }
            return sqlDbType;
        }
```

The reverse should be simpler with only Udt and Structured requiring special handling.

Comment: Are not Geometry and Geography user defined types in the CLR. There may be others, but I read that a short while ago in the MS documentations. Hence they should map to System.Data.SqlDbType.Udt?